# When does SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed occur?

Tags: ios

Can `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` (checked in `updatedTransactions`) occur only for new purchases, or also for restored transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll only ever get SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored as the transaction state for a restored transaction, never anything else.

If the restore fails, the transaction observer will get the paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError: message.

If the restore completes successfully, all the previous transactions are delivered to updatedTransactions at once, with the state SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored.

If the restore fails, you'll get the failedWithError message, but updatedTransactions won't be called at all.

Comment: ...and you may get this at the next purchase, if you forgot to finish the previous payment transaction.

Comment: So I conclude that `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` can only occur for new purchases, right?